# How much space do string.Empty and null take?

Tags: c#, .net

How much memory do an empty string and `null` take?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079753/how-much-space-does-string-empty-take-in-clr), which tells about the `String.Empty` memory allocation but not `null`.

If I want to store an empty string or `null` in session which one would take less space?

```
    class MyClass
    {
        public string One { get; set; }
        public string Two { get; set; }            

        public MyClass(string one,string two)
        {
            One = one;
            Two = two;
        }
    } 
    class Main
    {
       var emp = new MyClass(String.Empty, String.Empty);
       var nul = new MyClass(null,null);
    }
```

Comment: Guess it's another one of those premature optimization questions... first realize that the null reference and the empty string are semantically different things, then decide how you want your program to operate based on that. Stuff like memory management for these little things is up to Microsoft to worry about, not you.

Comment: BoltClock: I'd say that qualifies as an answer already :-)

Comment: Jon Skeet does a pretty good job explaining this already, in the link you provided us with.

Comment: @Joey: Ha, I thought so too, but I don't know the answer to the actual question so I'd rather not post it as one.

Comment: @BoltClock : Jon Skeet explained it very well in the link provided but i was not sure about the null part.It was more for the internal understanding of clr than implementing.:)

Comment: Agree with @BoltClock, even the right answer NOW can become wrong on next .NET service pack update. All these stuff is up to provider, so Microsoft, so potentially is a subject to change.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Within `MyClass`, there'll be absolutely no difference. Both will be "the size of a reference" - either 4 bytes or 8 bytes. It would also take the same amount of space if the values referred to any other strings.

Of course the empty string *object* takes up space, but it takes up that the same amount of space however many other references there are to it. (In other words, whether *you* refer to it or not will make no difference to memory... the `string.Empty` field will still refer to it, so it's not like it can ever be garbage collected.)

Comment: @Joey: I'm not sure what you mean by that. It's always a non-null value, yes... but it refers to an object, so that takes up space.

Comment: Of course, but that object exists, regardless of whether you reference it or not, so that size doesn't exactly count. Ah, nevermind, you said the same already.

Answer (score 7):

Both the same, I guess. One is the null reference (i.e. likely some magic internal reference value reserved for `null`) and one is a reference to a static field in a class. I doubt they'll be different memory-wise. Note: This is a guess, not knowledge, but whatever the actual answer is, I doubt you'll see big differences. Expect them in the range of a few bytes, if that much at all.

In any case, why are you worrying about this instead of using your time to solve actual, interesting or important problems?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something like free the space used by the string, and it doesn't matter which one you pick, use `null`. It could save memory, possibly (doubtful though since `String.Empty` is pooled) but it doesn't really matter. `null` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Go with null if you want the data to literally represent nothing.  Go with string.empty if you literally want the string to be empty (ie if you want to manipulate that empty string later on).  Memory should not be the issue at hand here.