# memory for unassigned variables in C#

Tags: c#, variables, memory, memory-management, unassigned-variable

```
//Consider this declaration
string name;
```

Here string variable *name* is an unassigned variable,does this declaration reserve any memory for *name* if it does not initialised?

Comment: If it's not used anywhere it will probably be stripped out by the compiler

Comment: that's generally what declaring a variable does, but if it's never used the compiler will probably optimize that away.

Comment: Is it a class field or a local variable?  The answer is different depending on the place you are using the code.

Comment: Who cares? If you're genuinely not using it, kill it.

Comment: Using ILSpy, I can confirm that `string name;` and `string name = "Test";` are optimised away from DEBUG and RELEASE builds if they are not used elsewhere in a method.

Comment: I recommend reading Jon Skeets answer here [how-much-space-do-string-empty-and-null-take] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601446/how-much-space-do-string-empty-and-null-take) as it will explain a lot. TL;DR a `string` variable is a reference, thus it will take up the size of a reference (e.g. 4 bytes on 32bit CPU) even if it's NULL.

Comment: @JasonEvans -if the variable is a member of class situation is different right?

Comment: Yes, if it's a `field` in a class, then it will never be removed, even if it's NULL or not used elsewhere.

Comment: @JasonEvans Not necessarily.  If it's `private` and it's never read from within the class, the compiler can in fact determine that it's unused.  Or if the field is `internal` and never accessed anywhere in the assembly.  If it's public then it'd need to be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not unassigned.  All classes/structs receive their default value.  For a string it is `null`.

If it is a local variable, then optimisation will tend to remove it.  If its an instance variable then memory will be allocated (I think, C# spec is unclear).

Comment: why you are saying "it is not unassigned".if it is a local variable and if i try do any operation on name,Compiler shows "use of unassigned variable".

Comment: @ShamseerKSmr And it's quite right in its error; you cannot use an unassigned variable.  You need to assign a value to it first.

Answer (score -1):

A variable local to a method doesn't reserve any memory, registers are allocated to it depending on how it is used and how other variables are used. As long as it's not used, no register is allocated to it.

You can have a large number of variables inside a method but there is a limited number of register in your CPU so the compiler optimize your code to re-use registers. For more information, see [Register allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation).

No, `string name;` doesn't *reserve* any memory.

Comment: Local variables *may* be enregistered, and they may not be.  To say that locals never consume memory is very much false.  In fact, a pretty significant percentage of local variables in most programs end up spending at least *some* time in memory.

Comment: They don't *reserve* any memory (implying when they are not used).

Comment: Stack space will be allocated for the local variable, which is going to end up reserving memory.  If the compiler optimizes it out because it's unused, then there will be no existence of the variable at all at runtime (not even a register).